# HTTP Post with node.js request module

Tags: node.js, http, post, http-post

I'm attempting to make a POST request using node and the request module and I can't get it to work (I'm getting a 301 response). I'm trying to post to a URL that takes the following parameters accessToken, wager, chance, and direction.

here's my code:

```
var request = require('request');

function repeater() {
    request.post(
    'https://betterbets.io/api/betDice', 
    { form: { accessToken: 'myToken', wager: 0.000000002, chance: 49.5, direction: 0 } }, 
    function(err, response, body) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log(response);
        repeater();
    });
}

repeater();
```

I'm not sure what to do. I've had no problems using the request library for GET requests but I can't figure it out with POST requests for the life of me.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the headers

```
headers: {'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
```